# how to host an exe with a dynamic commandline parameter

Tags: exe, command-line-arguments, nsis, web-hosting

I have an installer exe which takes a channel_id param as a command line parameter and uses it.
The channel_id may be different for different downloads and installs.
I want to host my installer exe on web in such a way that when it's downloaded and executed (by double clicking) the channel_id is passed to it in someway ,which should be equivalent to running the installer exe in cmd with channel_id as below.

`cmd> myinstaller.exe channel_id`.

How is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [append data to the end](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) of the .exe file.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am gonna use your suggestion.

Comment: Take in mind that if you are digitally signing your installers, you'll need to do so after appending the data to the end of the file because if you append data to a signed exe, you'll break it.

Comment: While it requires more code on the server, it is possible to embed extra data without breaking the signature...

Comment: Well we need to digitally sign it once, but append data again & again , for each download may be. So is this solution still applicable

Comment: How can I use this tool to append data in exe with affecting the signature ? It just add,delete,copy,extract signature, that too it makes the signature invalid.

Comment: disitool.py inject I'm guessing

Answer (score 1):

You can include your param in the name of the file. For example, instead of setup.exe, call it setup_XXXX.exe. Then from NSIS you can read and parse `$EXEPATH` and extract your param from the filename.

Comment: This could have solved it but the param is about 300 chars long and may contain special characters like % = etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most reliable way to do this (if there is any), but you could probably check for the Zone.Identifier. I'm not aware of a way to this natively in NSIS, but you might be able to achieve by parsing the result through the commandline.

Try

```
nsExec::ExecToLog 'more < "$EXEPATH:Zone.Identifier"'
```

or

```
nsExec::ExecToLog 'dir /r "$EXEPATH"'
```

I've also found several Powershell (and VisualBasic) scripts that allow interacting with [Alternate Data Streams](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx), but personally I'm not a big fan of using third party scripting languages.