# Appending/Replacing data in exe without breaking its digital signature

Tags: exe, code-signing, digital-signature, digital-certificate

**Background:**

I have an application to which I want to pass a param at download time, which is actually the id of the advertiser from which it got downloaded. We use this id to report successful installation.
This param will be different for different advertisers. Somebody suggested me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605870/how-to-host-an-exe-with-a-dynamic-commandline-parameter) to append the param data at the end of the exe and fetch it. I was able to do so perfectly.

**Problem:**

The problem now is that if we append in the exe, it breaks the digital signature of exe. If I replace the data with same amount of other data, the digital signature tab remains, but the digital signature becomes invalid.

So is there any way to append/replace data in exe without bothering its digital signature?

Comment: *is there any way to append/replace data in exe without bothering its digital signature* - if there was, the signing mechanism would be broken. Can't you simply sign the exe again just after adding the parameter? That would also be a barrier against misuse by your advertisers...

Comment: I dont know how if there are any API for signing the exe on the fly ?

Comment: @smilepleeeaz In general, yes, you can sign the EXE in code. This is called Autenticode Signatures and if you do the search, you will find information on making them in code.

Comment: @mkl *is there any way to append/replace data in exe without bothering its digital signature - **if there was, the signing mechanism would be broken.*** Well, There is: http://blog.barthe.ph/2009/02/22/change-signed-executable/

Comment: *Well, There is:* - Ok, then **that signing mechanism is broken** ;) That being said, for the areas mentioned it makes sense that they are excluded, merely their size could have been fixed by a serious signing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound too achievable, maybe make the download a zip with the signed exe and a text file with the code (which it then reads).

Bit of a wild stab in the dark would be to try using [NTFS Alternate Data Streams](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml)

- This may or may not invalidate the signature
- You may or may not be able to configure mime types such that the exe could be a single download.
- The additional data may or may not be preserved when a file is zipped.

Comment: As the OP want the parameter to be added at download time (I assume first the parameter is added, then the changed file is downloaded), alternate streams are no solution as they would be lost during file download.